How to create composite partition in mysql 5.7?
I have one table parcels, where I have 3 columns ID, PAYMENT_STATUS, CREATED_AT. It does not have any partition yet. This table has 30 million rows. Now I want to optimize this table, want to introduce partition here, so gradually I can remove older data. So as per my requirement partition candidate keys are CREATED_AT & PAYMENT_STATUS. So I am assuming composite partition or sub partition will be idea for my case. I ahve trier many ways to do this, but cant do this properly. Sharing my sqls here.
CREATE TABLE test_rnd (
    `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `PAYMENT_STATUS` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'unpaid',
    `CREATED_AT` datetime NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`ID`, `CREATED_AT`, `PAYMENT_STATUS`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


Create partition query
PARTITION BY RANGE COLUMNS(CREATED_AT, PAYMENT_STATUS) (
    PARTITION p_created_false_unpaid VALUES LESS THAN ('2024-02-01', 'unpaid'),
    PARTITION p_created_true_unpaid VALUES LESS THAN ('2024-02-01', 'paid'),
    PARTITION p_created_false_paid VALUES LESS THAN ('2024-03-01', 'unpaid'),
    PARTITION p_created_true_paid VALUES LESS THAN ('2024-03-01', 'paid'),
    PARTITION p_max VALUES LESS THAN (MAXVALUE, MAXVALUE)
);

sub partition:
CREATE TABLE test_rnd (
    `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `PAYMENT_STATUS` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'unpaid',
    `CREATED_AT` datetime NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`ID`, `CREATED_AT`, `PAYMENT_STATUS`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
PARTITION BY RANGE COLUMNS(CREATED_AT) 
(
    PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN ('2024-02-01'),
    PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN ('2024-03-01'),
    PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN ('2024-04-01'),
    PARTITION p3 VALUES LESS THAN ('2024-05-01')
)
SUBPARTITION BY HASH (PAYMENT_STATUS) 
(
    SUBPARTITION p0_unpaid VALUES ('unpaid'),
    SUBPARTITION p0_paid VALUES ('paid'),
    SUBPARTITION p1_unpaid VALUES ('unpaid'),
    SUBPARTITION p1_paid VALUES ('paid'),
    SUBPARTITION p2_unpaid VALUES ('unpaid'),
    SUBPARTITION p2_paid VALUES ('paid'),
    SUBPARTITION p3_unpaid VALUES ('unpaid'),
    SUBPARTITION p3_paid VALUES ('paid')
);


Its not working. Need help to create sub partition here

Will the purging of old data depend only on date?  Or do you plan on keeping certain "old" rows based on status?

Subpartitioning

It is possible to subpartition tables that are partitioned by RANGE or LIST.  Subpartitions may use either HASH or KEY partitioning.

You try to subpartition by LIST which is NOT allowed.

You want to partition by the year. So you may try to partition by the expression which combines the year and formalized status. For example, use the next partitioning expression: CONCAT(YEAR(CREATED_AT), PAYMENT_STATUS = 'paid'). Create according generated column and use it in both partitioning and query condition.

Test this before deploying; I suspect that the CONCAT will get in the way of "partition pruning".

@RickJames That's why I tell Create according generated column and use it in both partitioning and query condition. I.e. partitioning by this column and filtering by this column.
